# FindNext from InputBox throughout Workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Noob here. I've found plenty of code on this site and want to say thanks to all those who contribute.

My question is I have a UserForm. I click a button to bring up an InputBox, where they enter a value to search for bank name, banker name, business name, etc.

I have the code to do the search no problem, but I want to be able to be able to continue to search all of the instances of the InputBox value. For example, searching for the name "Smith" and if the first one isn't the one I need, to continue the search until I've landed on the one I'm looking for.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rFound As Range
Dim strName As String

On Error Resume Next
strName = InputBox("Please Enter Search Value." & vbNewLine & "Entry Must Be Exact Cell Value!", "Search Value")
If strName = "" Then Exit Sub
For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws.UsedRange
        Set rFound = .Find(What:=strName, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            firstaddress = rFound.Address
            Application.Goto rFound, True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
Next ws
On Error GoTo 0

MsgBox "Merchant not found. Please make sure you typed it correctly.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Invalid Entry"
```

Comment: If there is more than one instance of a search value on a single sheet, how do you want the user to be able to find the cell that is needed? Do you want the user to click a 'Find Next' button, do you want to highlight the cells with matching criteria etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA already has a `.FindNext()` method for this very purpose:

```
Sub SO()

Dim inputString     As String
Dim foundCell       As Excel.Range
Dim wSheet          As Excel.Worksheet
Dim foundAddress    As String

inputString = InputBox("Please enter search term:", "Search")

For Each wSheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Set foundCell = wSheet.Cells.Find(inputString, , -4163, 2)
    If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto foundCell, True
        foundAddress = foundCell.Address
        If MsgBox("Match in " & wSheet.Name & " (" & foundCell.Address & ")" & vbCrLf & "Continue?", 68, "Match Found") = vbYes Then
            Do
                Set foundCell = wSheet.Cells.FindNext(foundCell)
                If Not foundCell Is Nothing And Not foundCell.Address = foundAddress Then
                    Application.Goto foundCell, True
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If

            Loop While MsgBox("Match in " & wSheet.Name & " (" & foundCell.Address & ")" & vbCrLf & "Continue?", 68, "Match Found") = vbYes And _
                    Not foundCell Is Nothing And Not foundCell.Address = foundAddress
                        Set foundCell = wSheet.Cells.FindNext(foundCell)
        End If
    End If
    If MsgBox("All matches in this sheet found - move to next sheet?", 68, "Next Sheet?") = vbNo Then Exit Sub
Next wSheet

End Sub
```

Comment: No worries, and if you wish to do so - here is the MSDN article for reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx

Comment: Also, FreeMan's comment about `On Error Resume Next` - I can't put enough emphasis on how much you should take note of that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I know just enough to be dangerous, but have so much more to learn. Appreciate your assistance guys.

Comment: Actually, it seems to be having the popups twice. I click and its has the same msgbox twice.

Comment: @Jason needed another condition, see edited response

Comment: That works like a charm now. Once I have landed on the one I want, at what spot in the code would I put the code I need to pull it into a userform? Basically when it says 'Match Found' I hit 'No' and then it pulls the rowdata.

Comment: Is that within the scope of your question? I would suggest (for continuity of the site's search facility) for you to either edit the original question, or post that as a separate question.

Comment: Thanks @SOofWXLS. Appreciate your assistance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your search so your code 'remembers' where it left off, like this:

```
Option Explicit

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rFound As Range
Dim strName As String
Static First as Range

'On Error Resume Next
if First is Nothing Then   'we haven't found anything yet
  Set First = Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1)  'start searching at the beginning
End If

strName = InputBox("Please Enter Search Value." & vbNewLine & "Entry Must Be Exact Cell Value!", "Search Value")
If strName = "" Then Exit Sub
For Each ws In Worksheets
    With ws.UsedRange
        Set rFound = .Find(What:=strName, After:=First, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
        while Not rFound Is Nothing
            if first is nothing then
              First = rFound   'store off this address for use in our next search
            end if
            if first <> rFound Then    'we've found a NEW instance of the search item
              firstaddress = rFound.Address
              Application.Goto rFound, True
              MsgBox "Found one!"
              Set rFound = .Find(What:=strName, After:=rFound, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
            else  'we're back at the start, so jump out of the loop
              set rFound = Nothing
            End If
        wEnd
    End With
Next ws
On Error GoTo 0

MsgBox "Merchant not found. Please make sure you typed it correctly.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Invalid Entry"
```

A couple of points:

- I added `Option Explicit` which means your code won't run now because you never declared `firstaddress`. It's vital for your sanity to enable that option from the ribbon: Tools | Options | Editor then check `Require Variable Declaration`
- By declaring `First` as a `Static`, it will remain set between calls to your search routine. That way, since we're feeding `First` into the `.Find()` function, it will pick up the search where it left off.
- If you need to start the search from the beginning again, you could store off the 'last' search term - if the current term is different from the last term, reset `set First = Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1)`
- Additional note - `On Error Resume Next` is useful in **very** limited situations. This isn't one of them. It allows you to ignore an error in your code so that you can immediately handle it, which isn't what you want in this situation. The follow up `On Error Goto 0`, which reenables the default error handling should really never be more than 1 line of code later - not an entire subroutine.

Comment: I'm getting a 'Variable Not Defined' at firstaddress =

Comment: Sorry I saw that after. It runs, but after the first search it is just exiting the sub instead of being able to go to the next.

Comment: eh. Sorry about that. I've change `If not rFound...` to `While not rFound...` to make it loop. You may want something a little spiffier than the `MsgBox`, but that's a quick & dirty way to make it pause once it's move the cursor to the found box. If the user needs to be able to edit cells, then you need to put the `Exit Sub` back in there, and they'll need to re-run the macro each time, but it will search from the last found location. Also added a check to make sure it doesn't loop forever - it exits when it gets back to the first found cell.

Comment: It gets stuck at the 'Found One' msgbox and wont allow me to do anything else.

Comment: When you say "stuck", is that before or after you click the `OK` button?

Comment: It's after I hit 'OK'. The msgbox doesn't go away.

Comment: Ah, my bad. the `MsgBox` does go away, it's just that it's immediately finding the same cell & redisplaying the message. Look at the update to the second `.Find()` call, specifically, the `After` parameter.

Comment: If the `MsgBox` is suitable for giving the user time to look at what was found, you can look into the [`Buttons:=`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445082%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) parameter for some options to get actual feedback. Then, based on the button clicked, either search again, or exit the sub.

Comment: We're so close FreeMan! It does continue to search once 'Ok' is hit, but there is no way to get out of it.

Comment: For now, search til you hit the first one again, then see my [previous comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657995/findnext-from-inputbox-throughout-workbook/29658461?noredirect=1#comment47459289_29658461).

Comment: Is there a way to search the entire workbook instead of just the first worksheet? Again, I appreciate your help FreeMan.

Comment: Check the updates to the inner `While Not...` loop. Also, check the last point I just added.

Comment: Any help with the MsgBox? I'm having a hell of a time figuring out where to put everything.

Comment: Why don't you update your OP. Add your current code - that will make it a lot easier to figure out what's going on.